# I cannot understand why the range of integral of $x, y$ are from $0$ to $1$ when $x > 0 $ and $y < 1$.

Tags: probability, expected-value

First of all, I am not native speak so sorry for my poor English.

I am studying the text book named "the probability and statistics for engineering and scientists" by myself.

But I am not good at this subject.

So I need help from experts.(Please help me)

> Q) Let X and Y be random variables with joint density function.
>
> $$\ f(x, y) = 4xy (0<x, y<1) $$
>
> Find the expected value of $$\ Z = {\sqrt{(X^2 + Y^2)}} $$.

The problem is that I cannot understand why the range of integral of x, y are from 0 to 1.

Please explain that above..

Comment: ...because $f(x,y)$ is defined $0 < x<1$ and $0<y<1)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. does that means x and y are same domain(or axis)

Comment: You may want to start from $f(x,y) = 4xy, 0 < x,y < \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is some positive real number. Then if $\int\int f(x,y)dxdy = 1$ (as we must have for a probability density) then we must set $\alpha = 1$.

Comment: @ty.kim Your English is excellent!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The integrals are "technically" not on $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ only, but on $\mathbb{R}^2$: you do have
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} dxdy f(x,y) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
as... expected. However, by definition, $f(x,y)$ is non-zero only if  $(x,y)\in (0,1)\times(0,1)$, so we end up having
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} dxdy 4xy \mathbf{1}_{(0,1)\times(0,1)}(x,y) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
= \int_{(0,1)\times(0,1)} dxdy 4xy \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$

This is because $\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)\times(0,1)}(x,y)$ is by definition zero when $(x,y)\in(0,1)\times(0,1)$, and $1$ otherwise *(it is the indicator function of $(0,1)\times(0,1)$)*.

Comment: thank you.. I will try to understand this question based on your answer

Comment: @ty.kim You're welcome. If you have any doubt or further question, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people write “$0<x,y<1$” to mean “$0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$”,
similar to how one might write “$x,y \in (0,1)$” as an abbreviation for “$x \in (0,1)$ and $y \in (0,1)$”. And I think this is what's meant here. But this notation is a bit dangerous, since it can be interpreted (as you seem to have done) as “$0<x$ and $y<1$”, so I would recommend avoiding it.

Comment: "as you seem to have done" Based on the last sentence, *"The problem is that I cannot understand why the range of integral of x, y are from 0 to 1."*, that  does not look like what happened.

Comment: @ClementC.: My conclusion is based on the phrasing “when $x>0$ and $y<1$” in the **title** of the question. And I'm thinking that with this misinterpretation, it would indeed be hard to understand why the book integrates both $x$ and $y$ from 0 to 1 when computing the expected value.

Comment: That's fair. ${}{}$

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks a lot!